# Can't enable NFC on HTC One X

Tags: htc-one-x, htc, nfc

On clicking the NFC checkbox in settings, it turns off by itself after about 2 seconds.

It's a used phone which I bought from a friend more than a year ago and it's always been like this since it had ICS and it currently has Jellybean MR1.

Comment: A very vague idea: I don't remember which device it was, but at least in one case NFC seemed somehow "bundled" with Bluetooth. If BT was disabled, NFC would turn off, too. Might be pure co-incidence, but worth a try.

Comment: Nope. Turns off even with Bluetooth enabled.

Comment: OK, was worth a try. I'm out then (except for "contact the service", if any).